# Synth override text drawing on button

Tags: java, synth

Is it possible to use painter or some other technique to customize text 
drawing on controls with synth?

I know you can implement `paintButtonBorder` and `paintButtonBacground` in SynthPainter, but I was wondering is there a way to do it with text? Maybe some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would create a `SynthGraphicsUtils` subclass, override `paintText(SynthContext ss, Graphics g, String text, Icon icon, int hAlign, int vAlign, int hTextPosition, int vTextPosition, int iconTextGap, int mnemonicIndex, int textOffset)` and return an instance of your subclass from your button `SynthStyle`'s `getGraphicsUtils(SynthContext context)` method.

Anyway, if you are going to delegate painting to the super implementation, be wary of certain details if `text` is in HTML (begins with the `<html>` tag):

1. The super implementation will paint `ss.getComponent().getText()` instead of `text`.
2. The super implementation will manually set the text color before painting. For unstyled text, this will be `ss.getComponent().getForeground()`. For styled text, this will match the color specified in HTML/CSS.